# CSS Select paragraphs and figures except the last

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can a select with css all elements inside the article element, like paragraphs and figures and give the last element a different style?

```
<article>
   <p> paragraph </p> 
   <p> paragraph </p>
   <p> paragraph </p>
   <figure><img src=""></figure>
   <p> paragraph </p><!-- This will have a background red -->
</article>
```

And at another place the same but this time the last element is a figure element:

```
<article>
   <p> paragraph </p> 
   <p> paragraph </p>
   <p> paragraph </p>
   <figure><img src=""></figure><!-- This is the last element and should have another style, like a different background color -->
</article>
```

Comment: Either use [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) or [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) in combination with `:not()`. It is slightly unclear which you would want though.

Comment: Oke, so if all paragraphs have a margin-bottom of 30px, I want the last element, whether a figure or paragraph element is, style with a margin-bottom: . So short, the last element inside the article should have a margin-bottom of 0 px. Hope this is clear for you now! @JoshCrozier